# Why is my react flux function not defined?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, state, flux

I have been successfully writing a reactjs app.  It works well.  I have been writing a new component to take lat and long coords from State and pass it to a function I defined called `handleMouseOver` and bound it to `this` in the constructor state is defined in.  the same way I have in other components i have written The work as expected.

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';


import MapStore from '../../../stores/MapStore';

require('styles/Nav/Nav.scss');

export default class BathroomList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      lat: MapStore.getLat(),
      long: MapStore.getLong()
    }
  }

  handleMouseOver () {
    console.log( 'Hover' + Date.now() )
    MapActions.setBathroomListMap(this.state.lat, this.state.long)
  }

  render() {
    let listSrc = MapStore.bathrooms.listSrc;
    const bathrooms = MapStore.bathrooms.map(function(bathroom, i, mouseOver) {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <div className='bathroom-list' key={i}>
            <button onClick={this.handleMouseOver()} ><h1> {bathroom.bathroomName}</h1></button>
            <h2>{bathroom.description}</h2>
            <div className='dates'>
              <div className='date'>Found: {bathroom.date_found}</div>
              <div className='date'>Confirmed: {bathroom.last_confirmed}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        {bathrooms}

        <div className='bathroom-map'>
          <iframe src={listSrc} className='map-frame' />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error i am getting `BathroomList.js?ddeb:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleMouseOver' of undefined`.

I am thinking it is not defined in the scope of the `const bathrooms = MapStore.bathrooms.map(function(bathroom, i, mouseOver)` function.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is correct.

Change `MapStore.bathrooms.map(function(bathroom, i, mouseOver) {`

to: `MapStore.bathrooms.map((bathroom, i, mouseOver) => {`

Also the following looks like an error to me:

`<button onClick={this.handleMouseOver()}>`

You want this action to happen on click right? Not when you're defining the component. Change this to:

`<button onClick={this.handleMouseOver}>`